# C# SDK to Insert/Update/Delete/Select Data from and into Salesforce

Tags: rest-api

Are there any C# SDK to do Insert/Update/Delete/Select from and into Salesforce.
I know that i can use REST API, but was looking for any C# SDK

Answer (score 2):

There is! It’s called [Force.com Toolkit for .NET](https://github.com/wadewegner/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET)

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the [other answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/337092), you don't strictly need a toolkit, though it does make it easier. You can go to Setup > Integrations > API, download the WSDL, and import it in to your code by using the [Add Web Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/step-2-adding-a-web-reference) option in the Solution Manager. It's been a while since I've done this personally, but it's relatively painless, and only has a few extra hoops as opposed to using a toolkit (notably, you have to reset the Endpoint after authentication). Going the "[Do It Yourself](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_developer_environment_dotnet_tipsheet.meta/salesforce_developer_environment_dotnet_tipsheet/salesforce_developer_environment_dotnet_overview.htm)" route opens the possibility of using OAuth, JWT, etc options, rather than limiting yourself to what the toolkit provides.

Comment: ..and here's the official guideline for the DIY route: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_developer_environment_dotnet_tipsheet.meta/salesforce_developer_environment_dotnet_tipsheet/salesforce_developer_environment_dotnet_overview.htm :)

Comment: @Ideasforce Thanks for the link.